# No Localization found for additional url

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, localization

SDL Sites 9.1 and DXA 2.2 is set up, DXA 2.2 Default site is working on a defined URL.
When we wanted to set up a local web app to work with for example http://localhost:9070, we did the following:

- changed web.config and all configuration files to match the staging environment
- built app
- changed Website configuration (Set-TtmWebsite to have two base URL, where the second one matches to http://localhost:9070)
- Checked topology DB and the URL is there also
- Checked in CM Topology section and it shows the URL

When we open URL locally or on the server, there is information *No matching Localization found for URL 'http://localhost:9070/'*

Locally, there is a Binary folder, but it contains only the system/config folder.

Any idea what this second URL is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Topology Manager Mapping changes - actually this is automatically propagated to the Discovery Service database. but I have seen some cases where the Discovery Service was out-of-sync with Topology Manager for some reason. You can force sync the Discovery Service using the **Sync-TtmCdEnvironment** cmdlet.

Or could be cached in discovery - try to restart and validate your new base URL is appears in the discovery database.

You can also validate using graphql query, The following sample makes a request to fetch the relevant mapping information for a Publication with the specified URL:

```
{
  publicationMapping(namespaceId: 1, siteUrl: "http://localhost:9070/index.html") {
    domain
    port
    path
    pathScanDepth
    publicationId
  }
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I have done already that cmdlet. After running http://DNS-NAME:8082/discovery.svc/PublicationMappings('8')/WebApplications, there are two base URLs, one for localhost (not working) and a second one for a full DNS name (working URL)

Comment: Republish the “Publish Settings” Page to ensure the URL configuration is up-to-date in DXA config (_all.json)

Comment: Done it, removed the Binary folder from website root, but no results. If I try with locahost:9070 same issue still (no localization found), if I use full site URL with DNS name it works. Tried with admin/refresh but no results.

Comment: This is very strange, but if I add new binding for example 9050, and add it as base URL for that website, http://localhost:9050 is working from both locations, server and from my local machine (for development purpose). Very, very awkward behavior

Comment: There was misconfiguration with additional URL as base URL setup

Comment: @LjiljanaEric what was the misconfiguration - in TTM?